# javascript - "Submit is not a function" error in Firefox and works fine in IE

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am getting the "Submit is not a function" error in Firefox for the below code. I    also tried  document.getElementById("editInvNotesForm").submit(); and
    document.Forms[0].submit(); etc . Using getElementById will not give any error but updated value of form is not submitted.I appreciate any help.

```
  <input type="submit" value='<liferay-ui:message key="btn.save" />' onclick="return validateNotes(this)" onmouseover="this.className='clsBlueButtonOver'" onmouseout="this.className='clsBlueButton'" class="clsBlueButton" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            </td>


    <script type="javascript">      


                    function validateNotes(saveButton) 
            {

                if(document.getElementById('noteText${itemNoteVo.noteNo}').value<=0 ){
                    alert(Liferay.Language.get('msg.enter-report-note'));
                    document.getElementById('noteText${itemNoteVo.noteNo}').focus();
                    return false;
                }

                 if (document.getElementById('noteText${itemNoteVo.noteNo}').value.search(/[<>]+/) != -1) {              
                    alert(Liferay.Language.get('msg.angle-brackets-not-allowed'));
                    document.getElementById('noteText${itemNoteVo.noteNo}').focus();
                    return false;
                }
                saveButton.disabled=true;
                saveButton.className='clsBlueButton';
                 document.editInvNotesForm.submit();


                return true;
            } 
            </script>


Thanks
```

Comment: What is the html for the form?

Comment: <form action="<portlet:actionURL windowState='<%= WindowState.NORMAL.toString() %>'>
<portlet:param name='struts_action' value='<%=actionURL %>' ></portlet:param></portlet:actionURL>" name="editInvNotesForm" id="editInvNotesForm" method="post">   
<input type="hidden" name="reportId" id="reportId" value="<%= callReportId %>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="noteNo" id="noteNo" value="${itemNoteVo.noteNo}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="actionRequested" id="actionRequested" value="edit"/>
<input type="hidden" name="investigationNotes" id="investigationNotes" value="${fn:length(investigationNotes)}"/>

Comment: How can I attach my JSP in here?

Comment: what is the actual rendered HTML look like for the form (view browser source) and you can actually update your question and put the form code there, so it's easier to read. I suspect it is because of how FF indexes its forms vs IE's method. That is why document.getElementById worked but document.editInvNotesForm doesn't. What do you mean the "updated value of the form won't submit"? What value are you updating? Have you verified what is being sent to the server using fiddler or Firebug?